# Elm - input type checkbox

Tags: functional-programming, frontend, elm, reactive

I'm trying to set a `type` attribute for input:

```elm
input [ type "checkbox" ] []
```

But I get an error:

> ```elm
> It looks like the keyword `type` is being used as a variable.
> input [ type "checkbox" ] []
>        ^
> Rename it to something else.
> ```

When I try to use

```elm
input [ type' "checkbox" ] []
```

I get this error:

> ```elm
> Ran into a single quote in a variable name. This was removed in 0.18!
> input [ type' "checkbox" ] []
>        ^
> Change it to a number or an underscore, like type_ or type1
> Or better yet, choose a more descriptive name!
> ```

And if I try

```elm
input [ type_ "checkbox" ] []
```

I get another error:

> ```elm
> Cannot find variable `type_`
> input [ type_ "checkbox" ] []
>         ^^^^^
> ```

So how could I finally set this attribute?

Answer (score 10):

The correct function is indeed named [`type_`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Attributes#type_) and is located in the `Html.Attributes` module. Ensure that you are importing it correctly.

```
-- this exposed type_, checked, and value (as examples)
import Html.Attributes exposing (type_, checked, value)

-- alternatively, to expose everything,
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you are missing an import statement in your elm file, you can import just that attribute via

```
import Html.Attributes exposing (type_)
```

or, just import everything, like so

```
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
```

then the example you posted would work.

```
input [ type_ "checkbox" ] []
```

What I Like to do when I am writing html in elm, and need to look something up, is use [this site](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Attributes) and in the top right I can just search for the thing I am looking for. Comes complete with examples even! :)

Happy Elming!